# Trouble getting XML converted into variable in C#

Tags: c#, xml, swagger, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to get an XML from Swagger. Let's just say the XML is this:

```
<note>
 <to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

(HOwever, in reality my XML is MUCH larger). So if the above is being returned from swagger, how would I store these exact results in a variable in C#? Let me know if you need more detail. In theory. I would love to just be able to capture all this data and store it in a string variable or XMLDocument variable. Thanks!

I have tried doing storing it in a XML document and even a string, but the part I am having trouble with is capturing the XML from Swagger.

Comment: Please show the code you have since it is hard to answer your question without any code at all

Comment: LINQ to XML will be easier to use than `XmlDocument`.  If you have an XML string, you can do [`var root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse).  If you have an XML stream, you can do [`var root = XElement.Load(xmlStream);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.load).  Beyond that, your problem is unclear.  How is the XML being "returned from swagger" and why are you having trouble parsing or loading it?  Can you share a [mcve] showing your code, and where you are stuck?  See [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.